# What are the numerical methods to handle float precision error under matrix multiplcation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Suppose you have probability vectors that represent the mixed state of a non-deterministic finite state machine and you represent transition symbols as matrices. These matrices must preserve the total probability, i.e. the sum of the components of $v_{in}$ must equal the sum of the components of $v_{out}$. More generally, you might consider any normed vector space and the matrices that preserve the norm.

However the homomorphism from the matrices under matrix multiplication to their determinants under real/complex multiplication introduces a computational problem.

The multiplicative nature of the process means that error grows exponentially with each iteration. On any real machine, float-precision error quickly get out of hand.

Are there any methods that allow us to compute the product of norm-preserving matrices on real machines?

### EDIT

Consider the probability vectors $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ and some error $\epsilon$. Let

$$
\mathcal{M} = \big(
\begin{matrix}
p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \\
\end{matrix}
\big)
$$

$$
\mathcal{M}' = \big(
\begin{matrix}
p_1 + \epsilon & p_2 & p_3 \\
\end{matrix}
\big)
$$

Since the determinant morphism is analytic in elements of $\mathcal{M}$, the determinant of $\mathcal{M}'$ is then $\text{det}(\mathcal{M}) + f(\mathcal{M}, \epsilon)$ for some $f$.

If we continue to take powers of $\mathcal{M}$, the determinant follows scalar multiplication, i.e.

$$\text{det}([\mathcal{M'}]^n) = [\text{det}(\mathcal{M'})]^n = [\text{det}(\mathcal{M}) + f(\mathcal{M}, \epsilon)]^n$$

The highest order error term of that expansion proportional to $[\text{det}(\mathcal{M}) f(\mathcal{M}, \epsilon)]^{n-1}$, leading to exponential growth of the error in $n$

Comment: Can you give an example where that goes wrong in a meaningful way, that is, where the error growth in the norm is the primary concern? I would think, but may be wrong in this, that the error in the components grows much faster than the error in the norm.

Comment: "However the homomorphism from the matrices under matrix multiplication to their determinants under real/complex multiplication introduces a computational problem."
Please elaborate!

Comment: "The multiplicative nature of the process means that error grows exponentially with each iteration. On any real machine, float-precision error quickly get out of hand."
I do not understand this. Orthogonal matrices preserve norms and this include the norm of the error. I do not understand the nature of the problem. Please elaborate on this point as well.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misconception on what the leading error term is.

The leading error term in $(a+ϵb)^n$ is $nϵ\,a^{n-1}b$, which grows linearly relative to the main value $a^n$. The last term $ϵ^nb^n$ falls exponentially to zero, if $ϵ$ is small enough from the start. The sum of all remaining error terms after the linear one is $O(ϵ^2)$.

Comment: I think I see that this a problem with any analytic function. In any real system, epsilon can never actually be taken to be arbitrarily small. There is no upper bound on O(epsilon^n) terms and therefore error grows at least exponentially in epsilon. And given that matrix operations require storing many more digits than their scalar counterparts, that exponential error shows up a lot sooner.

Is there any way to exploit knowledge of the norm-preserving nature of the operations to stave off that growth in error?

Comment: This seems to indicate that the single step is already wrong. The relative evaluation error should be a small multiple of the machine constant. Over $n$ steps you should see, if $n$ is large, an error behavior like $e^{cϵn}$. This is exponential, but with a basis that is very close to $1$.